# Add .active class to navigation when you're on the corresponding page

Tags: jquery, html, href, nav

I'm currently using a script, which adds an active class to links in the navigation. This is working fine for most of the pages and compares the href with the url.

The one issue I encounter is when the user lands on the domain and when the user clicks on the link to the homepage. The link to home goes to: `../` so there is nothing to compare for the script when you're on the homepage.

The script works for every other link i.e. `../contact` and `../blog/` because the script can compare the href to the url.

I thought about comparing an id form the link, but couldn't get it to work unfortunately. Below is the script I'm currently using, which probably needs to be edited.

```
$(function(){

var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");

    $('.nav-order a').each(function(){

        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Any reason why you are using a regex? (it sounds to me like if you were using the equal operator, it would match as expected)

Comment: when you know it's the homepage, you probably don't need a regex. you can simply hard code that part.

Comment: I have to admit, I have never done this before. To be fair I found this script online and thought it would suit my needs. Unfortunately I don't know much about jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ){
    /*you are on homepage*/
    $('.nav-order a:first-child').addClass('current');
}
```

Comment: Do I use this script instead of my own, or do I add this to my current script?

Comment: Try adding before your `each` statement

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response, I have tried adding it, but unfortunately it doesn't work. When the user lands on the homepage or simply when landing www.example.com every item in the navigation has the class active added.

Comment: You could remove the regex and do something like `if ( window.location.pathname == '/' ){ /*add active to home link*/} else if( window.location.pathname == '/contact' ){/*add active to contact link*/} else if( window.location.pathname == '/blog' ){/*add active to blog link*/}`